# Obj-c - NSArray property appears NULL in numberOfRowsInSection, but not in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a new array by filtering self.neighbourData into self.closeByNeighbours (a new array), and everything works great - the data appears as it should in viewDidLoad. However, when trying to return the number of cells for self.closeByNeighbours, the NSArray count returns NULL? Any idea as to why this is?

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *closeByNeighbours;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *neighbourData;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {

      NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


            self.neighbourData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
             [self.neighboursView reloadData];


            NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];

            DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
            [session setUser:userDictInfo];


            [session user];


            NSString *myData = [session user][@"user"][@"field_province"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];

            self.closeByNeighbours = [self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(province contains[c] %@)", myData]];



        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

    }

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if (tableView == self.neighboursView) {

        return [self.closeByNeighbours count];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework reloads the table view implicitly after the *view did load*.

At that moment `closeByNeighbours` is declared but not initialized therefore it's `nil`.

The completion block in `viewGet` is called much later.

A solution to avoid `nil` is to initialize the array at the beginning of `viedDidLoad`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.closeByNeighbours = [NSArray array];
    ...
```

And you have to reload the table view on the main thread in the completion handler

```
...
self.closeByNeighbours = [self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(province contains[c] %@)", myData]];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting to init `closeByNeighbours`. Try adding.

```
NSString *myData = [session user][@"user"][@"field_province"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
self.closeByNeighbours = [NSArray array: filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(province contains[c] %@)", myData]];
```

Or however you want, you just need to initialize the `closeByNeighbours` property.